# Facebook Analytics URLs white listing for Zero rate

Tags: android, ios, facebook, sdk

I have a query about whitelisting Facebook event logging URLs that are used by Facebook SDK.

Currently, I have found this domain is used for log events at Facebook Analytics by Facebook SDK:
https://graph.facebook.com

Actually, my client is Telecom provider that offer Data Internet to its customers so that, my client wants to Zero rate his app for his customers.

And my query is if I give the above-mentioned domain to my client for Zero rate internet for their App and how can I make sure that this Zero rate will work only for the target app, not for all app that is using Facebook SDK on the same device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of this is not Facebook Support Team. This is a general place for programming questions. Secondly there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: I actually want answer from Facebook

Comment: Then you should ask Facebook.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I already answered that question. There is no way to do that. Even if the ISP inspected the traffic the traffic is encrypted. So there is no way for them to see what app is making the requests

Comment: There may be a method that is used by attaching app_id with URLs that are calling by SDK to uniquely identify the app for whitelisting.

Comment: No. Because the request is encrypted using SSL there is no way to look at the URL

Comment: Can Facebook provide the subnet mask of this IP pool so that we can whitelist that?

Comment: graph.facebook.com is used by Facebooks own apps and thousands of other apps. So you would whitelist those apps too. But if you want the list of IPs there is a command on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler to get all of Facebooks IP addresses. And yes all of those can be used by graph.facebook.com

Comment: Thank you WizKid, for your response, it will helpful for me.

Comment: Any alternative soution for this?

Comment: No there is no solution.